# How do I remove equation numbers while using {align}?

Tags: align

Here's my code. I would like to not show the equation numbers to the right of the equations. Is that possible?

```
\frame[t]{
\frametitle{An Example}
\vspace{0.1in}
\begin{itemize}
\item Since $A= ABUAB^c$ with $AB$ and $AB^c$ being mutually exclusive events, by Axiom 3, 
\begin{align}
P(A) &= P(AB)+P(AB^c) \\
&= P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)P(B^c) \\
&= P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)\lbrace1-P(B)\rbrace.
\end{align}
\end{itemize}
}
```

Comment: use `align*` not `align`